# Using grep for multiple search patterns

Tags: unix, grep

Consider I have the following stream of data:

```
BODY1
attrib1:  someval11
attrib2:  someval12
attrib3:  someval13

BODY2
attrib1:  someval21
attrib2:  someval22
attrib3:  someval23

BODY3
attrib1:  someval31
attrib2:  someval32
attrib3:  someval33
```

I want to extract **only attrib1 and attrib3** for each BODY, i.e.

```
attrib1:  someval11
attrib3:  someval13
attrib1:  someval21
attrib3:  someval23
attrib1:  someval31
attrib3:  someval33
```

I tried

`grep 'attrib1\|attrib3'`, according to [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/searching-multiple-words-string-using-grep/) but that returned nothing.  `grep attrib1` and `grep attrib2` do return data but just for the single pattern specified.

Comment: Not that it solves your problem, but it may be easier to follow and faster for grep to find if your regex is `attrib[13]`.  Making the common part longer is usually better.

Comment: what if there was no commong pattern between attrib 1 and 3? if they were named something completelty different?

Comment: in the real example, my attrib1 is called foo and attrib3 is called bar...

Comment: Then the `attrib[13]` trick won't work.

Comment: I don't understand -- does it **have** to be grep? axiom showed how to do it, but why not just use awk? Am I the only one who finds it simpler for this kind of tasks?

Comment: i would assume because searching for a single pattern would most easily be done in `grep` that so would searching for multiple ones as a matter of natural progression.

Comment: @amphibient If your question was answered, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 31):

`grep -e 'attrib1' -e 'attrib3' file`

From the `man` page  :

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>                 Use  PATTERN  as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used to specify
>                 multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with
>                 a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

**Edit :** 
*Alternatively* , you can save patterns in a file and use the `-f` option :

```
aman@aman-VPCEB14EN:~$ cat>patt
attrib1
attrib3

aman@aman-VPCEB14EN:~$ grep -f patt test
attrib1:  someval11
attrib3:  someval13
attrib1:  someval21
attrib3:  someval23
attrib1:  someval31
attrib3:  someval33
```

Comment: grep: illegal option -- e.  i am using SunOS

Comment: @foampile You may try and see if `-f` option is of any use.
Also note that for your example, `grep 'attrib1\|attrib3'` should also work fine.

Answer (score 23):

Very simple command:

```
 bash> grep  "attrib1\|attrib3" <file.name>
attrib1:  someval11
attrib3:  someval13
attrib1:  someval21
attrib3:  someval23
attrib1:  someval31
attrib3:  someval33
```

Answer (score 19):

Also egrep;

```
egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" file
```

Comment: Or `grep -E "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" file`

Answer (score 1):

This works, with GNU grep 2.6.3

```
grep "attrib[13]"
```

or

```
 grep "^[^0-9]*[13]:"
```

Comment: what if there was no commong pattern between attrib 1 and 3? if they were named something completelty different?

Comment: What are you looking for, a 1 or 3 on the end of the first word of the line and followed by a colon?

Comment: how can I do the same if I had strings with more then one character? something like: 

very-long-attribute-with-Jon-in-the-middle
very-long-attribute-with-Tony-in-the-middle
very-long-attribute-with-Richard-in-the-middle

so provide something that looks like: 
"very-long-attribute-with-[Tony|Richard|Jon]-in-the-middle"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell you are into. `grep -iw 'patter1\|patter2\|pattern3'` works on bash shell where as it doesn't work on korn shell. For korn shell we might have to try `grep -e pattern1 -e patter2` and so on.

Comment: Which shell you use has no direct bearing on what parameters the `grep` external command supports.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if there are multiple patterns be sure to put e option as the last options. For example,

> grep -iwe 'the' -e 'that' -e 'then' -e 'those' text

OR

> grep -iwe 'the' -iwe 'that' -e 'then' -e 'those' text
> OR
> grep -wie 'the' -wie 'that' -wie 'then' -wie 'those' text

works! But, if you put e first, like

> grep -eiw 'the' -e 'that' -e 'then' -e 'those' text

it returns an error.