# Multiple grep search

Tags: linux, grep

I was trying a multiple grep search, but for some reason it wasn't working:

Input:

```
What time is it in India
Time in Israel
Dogs are awesome
I want chocolate cake
```

Desire Output:

```
What time is it in India
chocolate cake
```

I used the command:

```
grep "(What time is it)|(chocolate cake)" inputfile.txt
```

However I got the an empty output instead. Would you know why this is going wrong?

Comment: Nice question. Good title and an excellent example of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using grep for multiple search patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610642/using-grep-for-multiple-search-patterns)

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the pipe (`|`) because it is a special character.

```
grep "what time is it\|chocolate cake" inputfile.txt
```

The parens in your regex are superfluous and can be left off. If you leave them, they must also be escaped:

```
grep "\(what time is it\)\|\(chocolate cake\)" inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `egrep` instead of `grep`. `grep` does not understand regexp you used:

```
$ egrep "(what time is it)|(chocolate cake)" input.txt 
what time is it in India
i want chocolate cake
```

More precisely, `man grep` on modern Unix-like system tells:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
>   lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?,
>   +, {, \|, (, and ).

So, following will work with the same result:

```
grep "\(what time is it\)\|\(chocolate cake\)" input.txt
```

Comment: or similarly, grep -e 'string1' -e 'string2' input.txt